# How can I see a list of fonts available in my blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, fonts, font-face

Right now I'm setting a font to my application, but I was just following an example. How can I know what fonts I have available to me?

```
FontFamily alphaSansFamily;
try {
    alphaSansFamily = FontFamily.forName("BBAlpha Serif");
    Font appFont = alphaSansFamily.getFont(Font.PLAIN, 9,
            Ui.UNITS_pt);
    setFont(appFont);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FontFamily.getFontFamilies()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/FontFamily.html#getFontFamilies()) to get a list of all fonts on the device.